# To DoList app using React and Array Javascript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary

Firstly, I want to ask forgiven for my English, I'm brazilian. I'm trying to create a React test app that render a to do task list using the method map in Javascript, but the react shows the array with empty values like the image. I want to know what I'm doing wrong. My code is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGV8e.jpg)

```
import React from 'react'

import {useState} from 'react'

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

import {MdCheck, MdEdit } from 'react-icons/md'

import './styles.css'


function Home() {

    const [task, setTask] = useState('')
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('')
    const [doTask, setDoTask] = useState([])


    function taskMsg (){

            setMsg(`The task ${task} has added.`)
            setDoTask(doTask.push(task))
            setDoTask(doTask.map(val=> <li> {val}</li>))

    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>
                    What you want to do today?
                </h2>
                <input type="text"
                onChange={e => setTask(e.target.value)}
                />
                <button id='btn1' onClick={taskMsg}> Add task</button>
                <p>Task: {task}  <MdEdit color='#88aa' size={20}/></p>
                <p>{msg}<MdCheck color='#55bb00' size={20}/></p>
                <p>{doTask}</p>          
            </div>
            <div>
                <Link to='/items'> 
                    <button >See my task</button>
                <p></p>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1):

There is issue in setting the state, if you want to add an item into an array you can use the spread operator

```
function taskMsg (){
        setMsg(`The task ${task} has added.`);
        setDoTask([...doTask,task]);
}
```

and in your return you could iterate through the array

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
 //Rest of Code Here
   <p>
      {doTask.map(item => {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <li>{item}</li>
          </Fragment>
          );
        })}
     </p>
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-bird-x6oyk)